# What is the default location for JMeter report file?

Tags: jmeter

Objective: I want to generate the Jmeter report file in CSV/XML format (irrespective of GUI or NON GUI mode, is it different?) with Avg, Std Dev,75th, 90th, 95th & 99th percentile included in. How to do it ? And where would be the default location of this file? Can it be changed mean the location of this report file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) doesn't contain "Avg, Std Dev,75th, 90th, 95th & 99th percentile" and so on

If you want to create a file with results for both GUI and non-GUI executions - you need to use a listener, i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and set the filename and the desired path to the file there:

[image]

Once you have the file you can generate CSV version of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```